# How to store two values returned by C++ TensorFlow function "SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits"

Tags: c++, c++11, tensorflow

I am trying to use a function of C++ TensorFlow (Machine Learning Framework). This function is "SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits" (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits).

As per the official document of this function: this function returns two output values: "loss" and "backprop". "loss" is of vector type and "backprop" is a matrix.

I don't the correct syntax and way so that I can store both the values. Currently, I am trying with this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<vector<float>, vector<float>>> cost = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits(args);
```

What is the correct way of writing above line in C++.

Thanks.

Comment: I am certainly not familiar with tensorflow but this looks like a class, did you try `SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits scewl;` and then `scewl.backprop` or `scewl.loss` to retrieve the result?

Comment: @Holt When I tried in the way you suggested, I got: error: "no matching function for call to 'tensorflow::ops::SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits::SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits()'"

Comment: When I am printing type of output from "SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits" function by using code: <auto cost = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits(args); cout<<typeid(cost).name()<<endl;> It is printing  "N10tensorflow3ops29SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogitsE". Please help me how to handle this..

Comment: Sorry, I meant `SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits scewl(args);` in my comment - Your second comment show that `Softmax...` is indeed a class.

Comment: @Holt Thanks a lot. As you said, `SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits scewl(args);` is working. But still I am unable to access `scewl.loss`. When I am printing type of `scewl.loss` it is `N10tensorflow6OutputE`. How to get values in `scewl.loss`.

Comment: You need to look the documentation of the [`Output`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/output#classtensorflow_1_1_output) class.